# How can I format price in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have this PHP code below which can format product price. I want to do this same task with javascript. Is there any way to do this same task with javascript?

### PHP

```
<?php echo number_format($saved_vehicles->Fields('basic_price'), 2, '.', ','); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var number = 123456.789;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number));
// → 123.456,79 €

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU', { style: 'currency', currency: 'RUB' }).format(number));
// → 123 456,79 руб.

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY' }).format(number))
// → ￥123,457

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3 }).format(number));
// → 1,23,000
```

your need to use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat). I think it's your choise